# How to check if an object is an instance of a Flow type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have two Flow types set up:

```
type Form1Fields = {
    fieldA
}

type Form2Fields = {
    fieldZ
}

type FormFields = Form1Fields | Form2Fields
```

Then I function that accepts a `FormFields` object as a parameter:

```
const myFunction = (fields: FormFields) => return fields.fieldA;
```

That's giving me the error `Cannot get fields.fieldA because property fieldA is missing on Form2Fields`.

I get what it's saying. According to the [Flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/), "when calling our function that accepts a union type we must pass in one of those types. But inside of our function we are required to handle **all of the possible types**."

So in `myFunction`, I'd need to do something like:

```
if (typeof fields === Form1Fields) { ... }
else { ... }
```

I could do that with primitive types like `number`, but it doesn't seem like I can do that with Flow types.

Is there a way to compare an object to Flow types, or is there a different way of solving this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how flowtype represents types under the hood. Have you tried `if (fields instanceof Form1Fields) {`? `typeof` will just give you `object`.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, the answer is [Disjoint Unions](https://flow.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions/). By adding a field to a type that "identifies" that type, I can check for it in `myFunction`.

```
type Form1Fields = {
    type: 'Form1Fields',
    fieldA: string
}

type Form2Fields = {
    type: 'Form2Fields',
    fieldZ: string
}

type FormFields = Form1Fields | Form2Fields

const myFunction = (fields: FormFields) => return fields.type === 'Form1Fields' ? fields.fieldA : fields.fieldZ;
```